# Make UITableViewCell contains a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I got a problem to make uitablveiewcell contains a uicollectionview.The tableview setting is:

```
 _tableViewOfSend = ({
        TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView *tableView = [[TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        tableView.delegate = self;
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200;
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        [tableView registerClass:[TopicWriteTextCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:kTextCell];
        [tableView registerClass:[TopicWriteImageCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:kImageCell];
        [self.view addSubview:tableView];
        tableView;
    });
```

and I added some constraints:

```
[_tableViewOfSend autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:_navBar withOffset:1];
[_tableViewOfSend autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeLeft ofView:self.view];
[_tableViewOfSend autoPinEdge:ALEdgeRight toEdge:ALEdgeRight ofView:self.view];
[_tableViewOfSend autoPinEdge:ALEdgeBottom toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:self.view];
```

The tableviewcell also add constrains for self-sizing. In my demo, i just used for presenting images.So i add an UICollectionView in it.

```
UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout alloc] init];
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5;
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5;

CGFloat widthOfScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
CGFloat cellWidth =(widthOfScreen - 20 - 5 * 2) / 3;
NSLog(@"cell height%f", cellWidth);
layout.itemSize =  CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);

_imageCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthOfScreen, cellWidth*2 + 10) collectionViewLayout:layout];
_imageCollectionView.delegate = self;
_imageCollectionView.dataSource = self;
_imageCollectionView.scrollEnabled = NO;
_imageCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6 green:1 blue:0.6 alpha:0.5];

[_imageCollectionView registerClass:[TopicWriteImageCCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kImageCellIndentify];
[self.contentView addSubview:_imageCollectionView];
```

And the add the constraints for the UICollectionView:

```
[_imageCollectionView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTop toEdge:ALEdgeTop ofView:self.contentView];
[_imageCollectionView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeLeft ofView:self.contentView withOffset:10];
[_imageCollectionView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeRight toEdge:ALEdgeRight ofView:self.contentView withOffset:-10];
[_imageCollectionView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeBottom toEdge:ALEdgeBottom ofView:self.contentView];
```

I just set the itemsize for a fixed value. The UICollectionViewCell only add a ImageView. and also add the left/top/right/bottom constraints. The item number is 5. In my opinion, I have fixed the itemsize, and add all needed constrains, it should be show 5 items with right height. But there is only 3 items, and the height is not right. It seems the cell didn't self-sizing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think your UITableViewCell is not growing because the collectionview has not intrinsecContentSize. You could add flowLayout to set the cell size. I don't know if you already did it. But I am just trying to guess because I am not sure I understand the question. :)

Comment: Thank you. I already add the flowLayout to set the cell size. It seems the UITableViewCell not growing. So how to refresh the UITableViewCell's height when add the UICollectionViewCell .

Comment: I can see you added your constraints to the contentView of the UITableView. So I can't find any other reason... Did you try to debug with the InpectorView to see the cell size and the active constraints? It's very helpful in these situations. What's the contentView size?

Comment: @TomCobo Thank you for reply.  Should I update the UITableViewCell when adding the UICollectionViewCell?  The cell size is correct and fixed, but the UITableViewCell is still default.

Comment: @TomCobo Thank you for reply.  Should I update the UITableViewCell when adding the UICollectionViewCell?  The cell size is correct and fixed, but the UITableViewCell is still default.